# Let the port 80 free of use but redirect classic http connection to 443

Tags: nginx, https, port

I'm currently redirecting users coming from the port 80 to 443 with Nginx.
But for this simple redirection, I need to allocate the port 80.

Is there any way to redirect users coming from the http to https but letting this port free? So I can bind something else to the 80 port?

Thanks

Comment: The application that you have listening on port 80 would have to take care of that redirect then … because that is who every client making an HTTP request (using the standard port 80) will be “talking” to. _That_ request has to be answered with the redirect, and so naturally only the service that listens on port 80 _can_ answer it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it fine to bind a UDP connection and in the same time a TCP connection to the port 80? So on the UDP I receive my data and on the port 80 I do the redirection to the port 443